# TripleDES Decryptor does nothing on first call to TransformBlock

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, tripledes

I'm having trouble understanding what's happening here.
The code below transforms a byte array with the encryptor and transforms it back with the decryptor. But the first call to TransformBlock doesn't do anything while the second one fills the correct values. Any idea what I'm doing wrong please?

```
        Random random = new Random();
        ICryptoTransform encryptor, decryptor;

        byte[] key = new byte[16];
        byte[] iv = new byte[8];

        random.NextBytes(key);
        random.NextBytes(iv);

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDESCryptoServiceProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        encryptor = tripleDESCryptoServiceProvider.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);
        decryptor = tripleDESCryptoServiceProvider.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);

        byte[] data = new byte[8];
        random.NextBytes(data);

        byte[] crypted = new byte[8];
        byte[] decrypted = new byte[8];
        encryptor.TransformBlock(data, 0, 8, crypted, 0);
        decryptor.TransformBlock(crypted, 0, 8, decrypted, 0);
        decryptor.TransformBlock(crypted, 0, 8, decrypted, 0);
```

Comment: Yeah, use `TransformFinalBlock` instead. Without it the code doesn't know if it needs to unpad and leaves the bytes in the internal buffer.

Comment: I tried this: byte[] crypted = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, 8); byte[] decrypted = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(crypted, 0, 8);  But I get a Bad Data exception

Comment: That is correct. CBC mode, the default, always pads, so you get 16 bytes in return.

Comment: Any way to avoid this?

Comment: [Yes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.paddingmode?view=netcore-2.1), [none](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.paddingmode?view=netcore-2.1) :P

Comment: Darn, should have been [this Yes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptographhttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.paddingmode?view=netcore-2.1y.tripledescryptoserviceprovider.padding?view=netcore-2.1&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.7.2). There goes the joke. How are you faring?

Comment: I found this code here, seems to work but I can't get my head around what it's doing: https://rextester.com/discussion/QSX88021/Des-encryption

Comment: Looking at random encryption code found on the internet is *never* informative, unless it is part of a specific answer or if it is used as a demonstration of a concept. **Don't even go there**. You're already using triple DES and CBC which is not a good sign.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting your code with `PaddingMode.None`?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes That actually solved it, thank you very much. Do you want to put that as an answer?

Comment: No, I'm happy that you solved it, but I think it is more debugging than anything else, and the initial question undoubtedly already has an answer, say... this one.